# Cannot add widget to AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to configure an existing AWS Dashboard with adding one new widget.

In Amazon Kinesis / Analytics application / Streaming application I click on the graphs 'View in metrics" of which I would like to add to my dashboard
[image: metrics]

In the next screen I click Actions / Add to dashboard
[image: addtodashboard]
after selecting my dashboard I click add, and then I can see my dashboard with the chart:
[image: dashboard-preview]

However, if I click on "Save" I get the following error:

```
There was an error while trying to save your dashboard:
The dashboard body is invalid, there are 6 validation errors: [ 
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/metrics/0", "message": "Should NOT have more than 4 items" }, 
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/metrics/1", "message": "Should NOT have more than 4 items" },
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/yAxis/left", "message": "Should be null" },
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/yAxis/left", "message": "Should match some schema in anyOf" }, 
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/yAxis/right", "message": "Should be null" }, 
{ "dataPath": "/widgets/5/properties/yAxis/right", "message": "Should match some schema in anyOf" } ]
```

I am totally clueless, as I did not enter anything manually, all I done was just clicking on the menu items. What is the problem here? I don't even understand the error messages even. I have 4 logs, and 1 chart already on the screen, this would be the 6th item if that is important.

**Update:** adding the source code of the template (I censored some sensitive information with "......."):

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 12,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "log",
            "properties": {
                "query": "SOURCE '/aws/kinesis-analytics/.......' | fields @timestamp, message | filter applicationARN like /arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-1:......./| filter messageType = \"ERROR\"| sort @timestamp desc",
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "title": "Error log (last 1000 records)",
                "view": "table"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 6,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "log",
            "properties": {
                "query": "SOURCE '/aws/kinesis-analytics/.......' | fields @timestamp, message | filter applicationARN like /arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-1:......./|  sort @timestamp desc",
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "title": "Full log (last 1000 records)",
                "view": "table"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 18,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "log",
            "properties": {
                "query": "SOURCE '/aws/kinesis-analytics/.......' | fields @timestamp, message | filter applicationARN like /arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-1:......./| filter message like / OEE Data Streaming app v / | sort @timestamp desc",
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "title": "Version - works only right after deployment, othervise look at the name of the jar file :) ",
                "view": "table"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "log",
            "properties": {
                "query": "SOURCE '/aws/kinesis-analytics/.......' | fields @timestamp, message | filter applicationARN like /arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-1:338785721659:.......") | sort @timestamp desc",
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "stacked": false,
                "title": "OEE app inside logs",
                "view": "table"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 24,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "yAxis": {
                    "left": {
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/Kinesis", "GetRecords.Records", "StreamName", ".......", { "id": "m3", "visible": true } ]
                ],
                "stat": "Sum",
                "title": "GetRecords - .......",
                "start": "-PT3H",
                "end": "P0D",
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and if I try to add the uptime widget, it's code is this :

```
 {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 6,
            "y": 24,
            "width": 6,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "yAxis": {
                    "left": {
                        "min": 0,
                        "stat": "Maximum",
                        "showUnits": false
                    },
                    "right": {
                        "min": 0,
                        "stat": "Maximum",
                        "showUnits": false
                    }
                },
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/KinesisAnalytics", "uptime", "Application", "...", { "yAxis": "left", "label": "uptime", "stat": "Maximum", "showUnits": false } ],
                    [ ".", "fullRestarts", ".", ".", { "yAxis": "right", "label": "fullRestarts", "stat": "Maximum", "showUnits": false } ]
                ],
                "stat": "Maximum",
                "title": "Uptime (Milliseconds) - Maximum",
                "start": "-PT3H",
                "end": "P0D",
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false
            }
        }
```

but I cannot save it now with the error message I described earlier.

Comment: Widgets are indexed from 0, so widget 5 would be the last (sixth) widget you added. Can you update the question with the source of the widget? Before clicking safe on the dashboard, click 3 dots on the widget -> Edit -> Source tab and copy the source.

Comment: @DejanPeretin I have updated the question with the requested information - I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the properties on axis definition and metric definition are mixed up.

Axis should not have the `stat` property: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html#CloudWatch-Dashboard-Properties-YAxis-Properties-Format

Metric definition should not have the `showUnits` property: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html#CloudWatch-Dashboard-Properties-Rendering-Object-Format

Try removing the `stat` property from both `left` and `right` axis definition. Also remove the `showUnits` property from the metrics definition (that should only be on the axis definitions).

If this was generated automatically, then it looks like a bug in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error message. What solved it for me was making sure that each Metrics widget format had the same number of elements.

for example, I tried to make one metric not visible in a metric array:

```
[ "...", { "id": "metric1", "region": "us-east-1" }]
[ "...", { "id": "metric2", "region": "us-west-2", "visible": false }]
```

This gave the `Should NOT have more than 4 items` error.  The error is obviously vague.

Adding `"visible": true` to the other metrics allowed me to save the dashboard without the vague error.

```
[ "...", { "id": "metric1", "region": "us-east-1", "visible": true }]
[ "...", { "id": "metric2", "region": "us-west-2", "visible": false }]
```